# What are some consequences of putting quotes in a WHERE clause for an integer column?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, syntax, query-performance

I have a table with a column `some_column` of data type `integer`.
I've noticed that my PostgreSQL 10.6 instance is smart enough to interpret both of the queries below as same:

```
select * from my_table where some_column = 5; -- no quotes

select * from my_table where some_column = '5'; -- quotes added
```

What are some repercussions of adding quotes in a `where` clause for an `integer` column?
Would it have performance effects on a large table of, say, 20 million rows?
(There is an index for `some_column`.)

Comment: You can compare the 2 execution plans.

Comment: They appear to be the same.

Comment: The question is, why do you want to supply a character value if you know the target column is integer?

Comment: @mustaccio: That's not the question *at all*. The OP didn't say he *wanted* to do that. Rather he wants to know about possible effects. The question is pretty clear and valid to me.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry, I have to disagree: it has "why" in the beginning and a question mark at the end, so it _is_ a question. You may not be able to answer it, and it's fine. Note I have said _nothing_ about the clarity or validity of the _original_ question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both do the same and you won't be able to measure any difference in performance.

#### Details

This is a ***string literal*** or ***string constant***: `'5'`

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-STRING)

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters
>   bounded by single quotes (`'`), for example `'This is a string'`. To
>   include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two
>   adjacent single quotes, e.g., `'Dianne''s horse'`. Note that this is not
>   the same as a double-quote character (`"`).

If there is no context from which a type can be derived, a string literal is initially assumed to be type `text`. (Not the case in your example.)

[The manual once more:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC)

> The explicit type cast can be omitted if there is no ambiguity as to
>   the type the constant must be (for example, when it is assigned
>   directly to a table column), in which case it is automatically coerced.

This is a ***numeric literal*** or ***numeric constant***: `5`

The [manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC)

> A numeric constant that contains neither a decimal point nor an
>   exponent is initially presumed to be type `integer` if its value fits in
>   type `integer` (32 bits); otherwise it is presumed to be type `bigint` if
>   its value fits in type `bigint` (64 bits); otherwise it is taken to be
>   type `numeric`. Constants that contain decimal points and/or exponents
>   are always initially presumed to be type `numeric`.

So a numeric literal starts out with a specific type. It may *then* be cast to a different type as the context requires - ***if*** such a cast is defined. That's a subtle, but important difference - which makes no effective difference in your case, since `5` is initially `integer`, which is exactly the type it needs to be.

But it matters in other cases. Try this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl1 (t int);
SELECT * FROM tbl1 where t = '0';         -- works!
SELECT * FROM tbl1 where t = int '0';     -- works!
SELECT * FROM tbl1 where t = int2 '0';    -- works!
SELECT * FROM tbl1 where t = 0;           -- works!

CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl2 (t text);
SELECT * FROM tbl2 where t = '0';         -- works
SELECT * FROM tbl2 where t = text '0';    -- works
SELECT * FROM tbl2 where t = varchar '0'; -- works
SELECT * FROM tbl2 where t = 0;           -- fails !!!
```

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
> ```

Because the numeric literal starts out as `integer` and there is no assignment cast defined for `integer` --> `text`. (Any type can be cast to `text` with an explicit cast (`0::text`) but that cast is not *assumed* here.)